# Validation rule preventing initial update

Tags: trigger, validation-rule

I have a custom object (S&E) that has a field that is essentially "update_locked".
This custom object gets created when an Opportunity goes to Closed Won.  The S&E object trigger fires on "after insert", and depending upon the Opportunity product, sets the S&E to be "update_locked".

At the same time, there is a validation rule that prevents anyone but SysAdmin from updating a locked S&E record.

The problem is that the validation rule is firing when I try to do the initial setting of the "update_locked" field!

I tried moving the set method to run on "before insert", but that did not help.

How can I accomplish my goal of:

1. Keeping a validation rule for everyone but SysAdmin, and
2. Being able to set the initial value after the S&E record is inserted.

Comment: Can you share the relevant bits of your Custom Object definition and proposed Validation rule here?

Comment: Are you able to share your validation rule? I'm guessing you have not used `ISNEW()` in it, in which case your fix is to change it to be `NOT(ISNEW()) && YOUR OTHER CRITERIA`, which will mean that the validation will only trigger for updates to records and not on record creation.

Comment: The Custom Object field is just a checkbox.  The Validation rule (which I did not write) is:

AND(
Advanced_Services_Locked__c = True,
$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator")

I will try the 'NOT(ISNEW())'

Comment: The thing that I find odd is that this seems like a fundamental "chicken vs. egg" problem.  Normally, I do not want anyone but SysAdmin to be able to update locked records, and the VR does that.  But how can the rule apply when the field that is being updated is the Advanced_Services_Locked__c  flag itself?   And, per Alex, the 'NOT(ISNEW())' did not work, because this is an update.   Perhaps I will have to change the logic to be in the Opportunity trigger when the S&E records are being created.

Comment: write the validation like...

AND(
    $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
    OR(
    AND( NOT(ISCHANGED(Advanced_Services_Locked__c)) , 
             Advanced_Services_Locked__c = true )
    AND( ISCHANGED(Advanced_Services_Locked__c) ),   
             Advanced_Services_Locked__c = false)

)